# How to split one table into two

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm working in sql server 2012 where I have table 
`Students` which contain 
`fields: StudentId, Name, City, Username, Password`.

I need split table Students into next tables: `Students` and `Users`. And table

`Users` must be have next fields: `UserId, Username, Password`.

And table `Students` must be have: `StudentId, Name, City, UserId`.

My question is: how can I do this by code?

P.S.: I'm new in sql. I know maybe this is dublicate, but I don't understand how to do this.

Comment: So what exactly you have a problem with? Creating a new table? Altering a table? Please say what you did by far.

Comment: How do you want to generate the `UserId` field?

Comment: @jwp it must be autoincrement in new table Users, but I haven't it on my table Students

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in the following steps:

Create Users table. Since you don't have UserID, you can generate it using an identity column.

```
CREATE TABLE Users (
UserID bigint IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
Username nvarchar(255),
Password nvarchar(255)
)
```

Insert data into Users table

```
INSERT INTO Users (
Username,
Password
)
SELECT
Username,
Password
FROM
[Existing table]
```

Now, create Students table

```
CREATE TABLE Students (
StudentID bigint PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
Name nvarchar(255),
City nvarchar(255),
UserID bigint FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES User(UserID)
)
```

and insert data into Students table

```
INSERT INTO Students (
StudentID,
Name,
City,
UserID
)
SELECT
StudentID,
Name,
City,
UserID
FROM
[Existing table] A INNER JOIN [Users] B
ON A.Username = B.Username
```

If the original table name is Students, create the above table as Students_New.
Then, after creation and insertion, you can use the below script:

```
DROP TABLE dbo.Students
GO;

EXEC sp_rename 'Students_New', 'Students'
```

Comment: `Constrcutive Criticisim:` Would it be not more safe to add An identity column to Original Students Table and then Add them values to new tables. The way you have created two separate Identity column in both tables, What guarantee you have that when you insert rows in these two column A student will get assigned same Identity value in both tables ????

Comment: Also the already existing Table is called students and OP wants to create another Table called Students, so have you in your solution will this not cause you to run into an error something like `An object 'dbo.students' already exists` :)

Comment: @M.Ali: I have created Identity column in only one table i.e. Users because UserID does not exist. In the other table, i haven't created an Identity column. Instead, i have used the existing student id column. Primary key on this column just makes sure that there are no duplicate StudentIDs. As far as the renaming goes, the original table name was not present in the 1st draft of question. That's why i have used [Existing table] in my query. If the original table name is also Students, then sp_rename would be required as you suggested :)

Answer (score 2):

Populate Students Table 1st , since you already have Students table in your table database you cannot have another table called students, so call it students_new inititally.

**Add UserID Identity COlumn to yout Original Table**

```
ALTER TABLE Students
ADD UserID INT IDENTITY(1,1)
```

**Students Table**

```
SELECT  StudentId, Name, City, UserId INTO Students_New
FROM Students
```

**Users Table**

```
SELECT UserId, Username, Password INTO Users
FROM Students
```

**Drop original Students Table and Rename New Table**

Now you can Drop the actual Students Table and Rename the `Students_New` Table to `Students`

```
DROP TABLE Students
GO

EXECUTE sp_rename 'Students_New','Students';
GO
```

Comment: That would work a lot better if the source table actually had a UserId field which it doesn't.

Comment: I dont have UserId in my table Students

Comment: @M.Ali but I need to alter two tables bu UserId which contains in Students table

Comment: I have used `SELECT cols INTO NEw_Table` syntax to create and populate tables on the fly. Later I used sp_rename to change the names of Tables and Column. Its is less coding for you and less hanssle.

Answer (score 1):

> i think userid is not there in table. so like @M.ali said first keep
>   one back of old table. also i think userid is auto generated.
>   So also create studentid in user table

first step ,

```
SELECT studentid, Username, Password INTO Users
FROM Students
```

now update back student table for inserting userid in student table

```
update student set userid=u.userid
from student a inner join user u on s.studentid=u.userid
```